# IOS Swift - API fetch (Able to fetch data in console log, but can't display it)

Tags: ios, swift, api, rest, native

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var data = [WeatherResponse]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
        title = "Værmelding"
        
        downloadJson {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
       }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let  cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].geometry.type.capitalized
        return cell
}
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetails", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController {
            destination.data_detail = data[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }
    
    

    func downloadJson(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        
        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/compact?lat=60.10&lon=9.58"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            print("checking for data")
            
            
            if err == nil {
            do {
                let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data!)
                
                print(weather)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completed()
                }
                  
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print(jsonErr, "is error")
            }
          }
            
        }.resume()   
    }
}



import Foundation
```

struct WeatherResponse: Decodable {
let geometry: Weather
let properties: Properties
let type: String

```
} 
// MARK: - Geometry
 struct Weather: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let coordinates: Array<Double>
}


 //MARK: - Properties
struct Properties: Decodable {
    let meta: Meta
    //let timeseries: [Timesery]
}

 //MARK: - Meta
 struct Meta: Decodable {
    let updated_at: String
    let units: Units
}

// MARK: - Units
struct Units: Decodable {
    let air_pressure_at_sea_level: String
    let air_temperature: String
    let cloud_area_fraction: String
    let precipitation_amount: String
    let relative_humidity: String
    let wind_from_direction: String
    let wind_speed: String
}
```

The code works when I fetch APIs as an array, but here it doesn't display. It might be because it is trying to read data from as a Dictionary. The code works fine when i fetch from APIs such as; Dota, JSON dummy data and apis that works with id.

Comment: You don't assign `weather` to `self.data` after you decode the json.

Comment: I can see that, how should I assign it?

Comment: Literally `self.data = [weather]`

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work.